# iTextSharp pdf Listbox form control looses right alignment

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a pdf form, and I am using pdfStamper to manipulate the values of listbox.

```
form.SetListOption("fieldname",String[]{"one","two","three"});
form.SetListSelection("fieldname",String[]{"","",""});
```

The listbox alignment is set to "right".  If I use a PDF editor and change the values myself, it displays correctly.

If I run it through iTextSharp, the listbox is left aligned.

Is this a bug, or do I need to do something else?

Comment: What version of iTextSharp are you using? That will help us to trace the problem better.

Comment: I have tried 5.0.2 and 5.4.3. I also tried the lastest 5.4.4, with the same result, although the textbox fields were now empty, so I went back a version.  Is there some way to reset the alignment property in code?